# Adding a folder to the Application folder

Tags: android, database, path, directory

I've used application folder

> data/data/com.xxx.xxx/databases/Customer.db

to store a database,it works fine and i could open and used it,but i wanted to add multiple folders to this path like

> /data/data/com.xxx.xxx/databases/b36f6e58-0971-4f79-aca0-dada4201d886/Customer.db

but when i download the database and put it on the path and when i want to open it, it throws Exception that couldn't open the database.i have also try downloading the db ,check and makeDir the path then move db to the path but it doesn't solve the issue.
is there anything wrong with adding another folder in application folder or am i missing something? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way:

```
File newDir = new File(getFilesDir(), "newDir");
if (!newDir.exists()) {
    newDir.mkdirs();
}
```

File inside newDir can be accessed with `openFileInput`/`openFileOutput`. For both you need a context

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i've tried making directory by File dir = new File (outputPath); 
            if (!dir.exists())
            {
                dir.mkdirs();
            } but it doesn't work either in opening db , and i'm sure that the folder exists(i'm checking it on moving function) and i can move my db to this folder.

Comment: did you used getFileDir to retrieve the root? File inside that path can not be accessed directly. You need to use openFileInput/openFileOutput

Comment: No i didn't.without adding a folder i could open and use the db without using openFileInput/Output in Application Folder, Can you explain more how can i open my db file with OpenFileInput() or why i should use getFilesDir()? is it just because of this custom Folder?.

Comment: @blackbelt: `mkdirs()` is sufficient -- you don't need both `mkdirs()` and `mkdir()`.

Comment: @Arash: You can only use `openFileInput()` and `openFileOutput()` with files, not paths to subdirectories. If you wish to use subdirectories, you will need to use `getFilesDir()` and standard Java file I/O. If your "db" is a SQLite database, that probably should not be in `getFilesDir()`, anyway -- [there is `getDatabasePath()` for that](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDatabasePath(java.lang.String)).

Comment: @CommonsWare and blackbelt : Thank you for your help , i solved the issue